# How to make a VB exception handling for no value in a Textbox

Tags: vb.net, validation

I want to catch an exception when user enter no value in a Textbox and try to process further by press a button, I know I can use "If else" statement to make it. but in terms of "Try and Catch" block, I dont know how. Here is the code sample.

```
Dim NameString As String

   Try
      NameString = OperatorNameTextBox.Text
   Catch ex As ArgumentException
      MessageBox.Show("Enter a String Value")
   End Try
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use validators to prevent a user from not filling in fields?

Comment: I would have to agree. Exceptions are to indicate something going wrong in the application. The user not entering a value should not raise an exception.

Comment: +1. Q "how do I tighten a screw with a hammer?" A "you don't, you should use a screwdriver instead"

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use the textbox "Leave" event (lost focus would probably work as well) and just check if text has been entered.  Not sure if that helps any..

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(....)

if textbox1.text = vbnullstring then

'Your Code'

end if
end sub

and then for your button_click event you can use the same code as in the leave event.

SchmitzIT answer is also perfectly fine to do.   There are many ways to check for nullstrings, all personal preference.

Comment: Hi, Actually I have used a simpler way to deal the problem, use an if statement to validate the value textbox, then put all the try and catch statements under it. it works perfect.